# prometheus segments are not sequential error

Tags: prometheus

I am wondering if my Prometheus install is completely busted or if I can still salvage it.

We had issues with the WAL which was taking too long to be process, and was creating an infinite crash loop as Prometheus was getting killed couple of minutes before it finished.

I saw advices to delete some segments in the WAL directory to make it faster, which I did.

But since, pod refuse to even start with the error

> "opening storage failed: get segment range: segments are not
> sequential"

I tried to to fully delete the WAL directory and restart, but even then I still get the error.

Any idea how I can salvage it ?